# Why a temp value cannot be used in a constructor with a const reference argument?

Tags: c++, const-reference

The code is as below

```
class A {};
class B
{
public:
    B(const A& a) {}
    void fun() {}
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    B b(A());
    b.fun(); // Error: left of '.fun' must have class/struct/union  

    A a;
    B b2(a);
    b2.fun(); //Okay

    return 0;
}
```

Why?

Comment: Most vexing parse at work. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse

Comment: Just a note, Clang is excellent at this.

Comment: @chris You mean that Clang outputs more informative error messages? Because I very much doubt it has "worked around" the most vexing parse...

Comment: @CodyGray, Yes, I do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code

```
 B b(A());
```

is not declaring an object of `B`, but rather a function declaration for a function `b` which returns an object of type `B` and takes a single (unnamed) argument which is a function returning type `A`(and taking no input). (Quoting from link below). Therefore, you saw that error.

See [C++ most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)